# What websocket to use with WebRTC on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, webrtc

I am trying to implement WebRTC on Rails, which is a tough task because I am new to Rails and web conferencing. I have followed a tutorial on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/ but it appears we need a websocket installed for this to work. I tried a few but have been hitting some walls. I then finally tried web-socket-js with which I could actually get the websocket object on the client side but my setup is still having issues getting the websocket server object on the server.js side. Does anyone know what websocket would work best with Rails/WebRTC or is there something fundamental that I am missing from this documentation?

Comment: Answering my own question after a long time of trying to get webRTC to work. EasyRTC is an open source tool that is really good for this. I would recommend.

Comment: how did you manage to communicate EasyRTC with Rails?

Comment: Yea I didn't actually as I swapped over to crosswalk because I need android too. But I am quite sure it is doable, because I have seen people do similar things with projects like webrtc-rails.